# Adding a submenu to a listview with an adapter?

Tags: android

I wanted to add submenus to my listview. I am currently using an ArrayAdapter for my list items. Is there anyway I can add submenus into my adapter or any other suggestions for easy ways to implement this? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can use ExpandableListView or else you can have a listview as an item in a listview.

Comment: Is the submenu available for each item in the listview? Or will it be a generic menu item in a actionbar for example?

Comment: How can i user see the submenu??? OnClick of your List Item??